# Had not or did not in this sentence

Tags: past-tense

I thought I had already replied to our email  but I ' did not or had not '

I think only the second one is possible but I am not sure because it is after thinking that I realised that I had not replied so may be 'did not'could also fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my ear, *hadn't* is more natural, but *didn't* is possible.

If you use *didn't*, you are choosing to move the temporal focus away from the time when you thought that - presumably to the moment when you found out that you didn't reply. This might be appropriate when you want to emphasis your surprise at that moment (*I thought I had already replied to your email ... but I **didn't**!*) Even in this case, *hadn't* is more natural.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical, and either is frequently appropriate.

> I thought [at some past time A] that I had sent the email [before time A], but I had not sent it [before time A]

is perhaps more consistent with the possibility that I did send it after time A but before now.

> I thought [at some past time A] that I had sent it [before A], but [I now know that] I did not.

is perhaps more consistent with the possibility that it has not yet been sent.

EXAMPLES

> I thought yesterday that I had sent the email the week before. But upon reviewing my “sent emails” today, I found that I had not sent it last week and that it was instead still sitting in “draft emails.” I just sent it off. Sorry for the inconvenience.

That is one possible example where “had” seems preferable to me.

Here is a context in which I prefer “did.”

> I thought last Monday that I had sent the email the previous week. Today, I was looking at my “draft emails” and discovered I did not ever send it. My fault. I shall send it as soon as I review the draft.

In other words, the difference is tiny, and I doubt anyone other than a careful writer who self-edits would notice it.